# Is there any point to drawing Fortune Slips at the Grand Narukami Shrine in Inazuma?

Tags: genshin-impact

Every day you have the opportunity to draw a Fortune Slip from Gendou at the Grand Narukami Shrine. It seems to be a random fortune every single time, but I can't help but wonder if there's some sort of gameplay advantage or reason to draw every single day.

[image]

An example of such a fortune slip (I pulled a "Great Misfortune" slip today):

[image]

Does the flavor text of the fortune slip have any real meaning? Or is this Genshin Impact's way of describing "fortunes" by way of items paralleling horoscopes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, there is no actual gameplay benefit to pulling at the shrine. The only real rewards for doing so is getting two Genshin Impact achievements:

- **Paimon's Lucky Day**

  - Pull a "Great Fortune Slip"
- **Just My Luck...**

  - Pull a "Great Misfortune Slip"

Comment: Completing achievements does earn you primogems, though, so there is a (small) benefit.

Comment: When I gathered the item my slip mentioned and fought a boss the slip was consumed when I opened the bloom. So they might confer a hidden bonus?

Comment: @DavidYell Interesting... I'll have to look into that.

Comment: You could also add that it unlocks a hidden world quest starting a certain patch (I don't remember which patch it was)